# Taking a quadratic function integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I take this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{x} (z- u)_+^2 du $$

which `+` means If $z$ is bigger than u its equal $z - u$ and else it's equal zero.

Comment: Questions like this are improved if you include a description of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t\leq\tau$, we have
$$\int_0^t (\tau-u)_+^2 du = \int_0^t (\tau-u)^2 du = \dfrac{(t-\tau)^3+\tau^3}3$$
If $t\geq\tau$, we have
$$\int_0^t (\tau-u)_+^2 du = \int_0^{\tau} (\tau-u)^2 du = \dfrac{\tau^3}3$$
Hence, we get that
$$\int_0^t (\tau-u)_+^2 du = \begin{cases} \dfrac{(t-\tau)^3+\tau^3}3 & t \leq \tau\\ \dfrac{\tau^3}3 & t \geq \tau\end{cases}$$
The above can be rewritten as
$$\int_0^t (\tau-u)_+^2 du = \dfrac{\tau^3-(\tau-t)_+^3}3$$

Comment: If I want to find the answer of question in terms of $(\tau - t )_+$ , whats the answer? If $ t $$<=$  $\tau $ How do you have $(t- \tau)$ in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but could you tell me how did you get $(t-\tau) ^3/3 + \tau ^3/3$ if $t  \leq \tau$?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this integral just be

$$\int_{\tau}^t du \: (\tau-u)^2 = \frac{1}{3} (t-\tau)^3$$